# Find and delete duplicate rows in matrix in QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis-3, csv, distance-matrix, delete, duplication

I used the OD Matrix to produce a list of the distances between all sites to all other sites via a network. This process produces duplicates, since it makes calculations in both directions, i.e., from Site 1 to Site 2 as well as from site 2 to site 1.

I tried to use the Vector general > delete duplicates by attribute tool to find these, but if one selects both ID and target, it deletes nothing, and if one selects the distance, it deletes others that are not duplicates.

I cannot import the matrix into Excel to edit (as I had planned to do) because the file is too large (2.14 million rows).

I want to reduce the result of OD Matrix down, by eliminating the duplicate rows (keeping (A, B) but deleting (B, A)).

Then I will want to filter the remaining rows by keeping only those under a certain threshold (11000), unless there are no lengths that short and taking the next shortest. I have been unable to find a solution for either of these in R or Python (but I don't yet know how to use either R or Python yet).

If the OD Matrix had more optional parameters it would help.

[image]

EDIT: UPDATE

I have run it again, with a smaller set of sites and the results were the same.

I ran the OD Matrix both as Layer as Lines (m:n) and as Points to Lines (n:) and got the same result.

I used a road network of the Roman roads downloaded from Ancient World Mapping Center.

I am using a set of coordinates comprising 131 sites (with elevations), so there ought to be 8515 unique distances. I get 17161 as a result.

I can edit out the duplicates with R; but it is slightly annoying one cannot easily do it with the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Avoiding duplicates**

Creating duplicates should only be a problem if both origin- and destination layer are the same. For different layers, only connections from input to destination are calculated. As a workaround if you have the same layer: duplicate the layer and set the original as origin and the copy as destination.

**Removing duplicates**

If you already have the table with duplicates, you can remove the double entries using `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Aggregate` and use this expression to aggregate (collect, integrate) the duplicates to only one feature. Duplicates are based on the total cost (rounded here to 2 decimals as the values for one direction and inverse direction might not be 100% the same):

```
 round( "total_cost",2)
```

Set the aggregate function to "first value" to keep the values in the fields.

*Screenshot: with 5 Points, OD-Matrix creates 5x5=25 connections. Running `Aggregate` reduces with the above expression reduces them to 11: the 10 you expect + one "self-connection" (from point 1 to point 1) containing value `NULL` (empty) or `0`:*
[image]

Comment: I tried the method for removing duplicates, but it removed much more than the duplicates (I can't figure out how it worked, as only links from sites with numbers in 800s remained, number of features only 1465). So I tried re-running the matrix with a duplicate, but the results were the same as before (2,146,225 features). 
As I have 1465 sites, the correct number of rows ought to be 1,072,380.

Comment: Without having access to your project, it's difficult to say why it didn't work the same way as here. So at least a sample of your data would be helpful.

Comment: I have a dataset of 1465 sites, with coordinates and elevation, and a Roman road vector. They work perfectly well with the QNEAT3 closest path. I will add a screenshot above of the table of sites.

Comment: The screenshot posted does not help much to understand what went wrong. It does not show what you exactly did and where the problem arises. If you could provide just a small sample of the data, that might clarify things.

Comment: I'll get back to this when on that computer again later. For the moment I used Excel for the smaller file and R for the larger file to eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: I added an update above.

Comment: Not sure - might have to do something with the geometry or topology of your network/points? See also here: https://github.com/root676/QNEAT3/issues/25 - Use `OD-Matrix from Points as Lines (n:n)` and set `Default direction` to `Both directions` (moving along the network segements both ways, avoiding "one way" streets), then the total cost for duplicates should be the same. Based on this value, you can use the Aggregate tool (as described in the solution) to delete the duplicates.  Also consider setting a `topology tolerance` > 0

Comment: The settings were already on both directions, and the topology tolerance was set for 600 meters (since 0 topology tolerance ended up leaving out a number of sites for some reason). I will check out the Github thread

Comment: OK, so as long as I don't have access to the data, I can just speculate.

Comment: I will try again tomorrow with the new rounding function above, and see what happens :)

Comment: The  round( "total_cost",2) appears to have worked; it produced 8500 lines.